# numpy: Faster np.dot/ multiply(element-wise multiplication) when one array is the same

Tags: python, numpy

I have to do dot product multiplications between two 1D arrays and then take the sum of the list as:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
import time
import random

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],dtype=int8)  # Same first array
b = [np.array([random.randint(0,100) for y in range(6)],dtype=float) for x in range(1, 1000000)]  # iterable of 2nd array

c = np.zeros(len(b))  # to store results

@numba.njit()  # benefits of numba
def sum_of_mul(list1, list2):
    return np.dot(list1, list2)

tstart = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(len(c)):
    c[i] = sum_of_mul(a, b[i])

final_average = np.sum(c) / len(c)
print('time taken', round(time.perf_counter() - tstart, 1))
```

**I am only interested in the speed of the array multiplication and not the setup.**
The dot product takes about 1.2 seconds on my pc.

Given that my first array is the same, and both my arrays are 6 elements in size, is there any faster way to do this?

Somehow make this into a multidimensional matrix multiplication? Pandas? Or use some fancy Library? I have an AMD GPU.

I've tried multiprocessing it and it takes 16x more time (most likely because I'm doing a relatively trivial operation on a small array).

numba helped speed this up.

EDIT: As per the currently accepted answer, this also was a huge speed up

```
np.mean(np.dot(a, b.T))
```

and making sure that a and b (/everything) are numpy arrays

Comment: Isn't this just `np.dot(b,a)`?  `np.array(b)` is (1000000,6) shape and `a` (6,)`

Comment: At the python numpy level they are different. `np.dot` includes the `sum` step.

Comment: I see your point and I have edited the question. There was no speed improvement with np.dot vs np.sum(np.multiply))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Baseline**

Your code on my system takes 1.16 sec for the last part (without initialization, the same way you measured it):

```
time taken 1.2
CPU times: user 1.16 s, sys: 176 ms, total: 1.33 s
Wall time: 1.16 s
```

Initialization part takes 5.5 sec.

We can drive it down to **6ms** with **pure Numpy** and **3ms** with **CuPy** (CUDA).

**Improvements**

1. Manage your types appropriately. You are using `int` and `float`, which are 64 bit python types.

With `np.float32` as base type for all your arrays, time goes down twice:

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],dtype=np.float32)  # Same first array
b = [np.array([random.randint(0,100) for y in range(6)],dtype=np.float32) for x in range(1, 1000000)]  # iterable of 2nd array
```

```
time taken 0.8
CPU times: user 743 ms, sys: 62 µs, total: 743 ms
Wall time: 762 ms
```

2. Use `numpy` types for data types and algorithms.

Your initial code mixes python lists and numpy arrays. On my pc it takes 5.5 for initialization.

Instead of list of 1_000_000 np.arrays(6,) each, you can have one np.array(1_000_000, 6). You can rewrite this part as:

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],dtype=np.float32)  # Same first array
b = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (1000000, 6)).astype(np.float32)  # 2nd array
```

This takes only 59 ms.
Note, that `np.random` returns results with dtype=np.float64.

Calculation will be very straight forward with pure Numpy:

```py
np.mean(np.dot(a, b.T))
```

This takes 6 ms.

```
CPU times: user 13.7 ms, sys: 8.03 ms, total: 21.7 ms
Wall time: 6.1 ms
1050.432
```

3. Speeding up with GPU

You can use `CuPy` - Nupy on CUDA. Cupy is great, because its API is nearly identical to Numpy:

```py
%pip install cupy

import cupy as cp

# initialization
a = cp.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],dtype=np.float32)  # Same first array
b = cp.random.uniform(0,100, (1000000, 6)).astype(np.float32)  # 2nd array

# calculation
cp.mean(cp.dot(a, b.T))
```

This takes 2.9 ms (I have here CUDA 11.3 on Tesla K80 card).

```
CPU times: user 1.22 ms, sys: 11.8 ms, total: 13.1 ms
Wall time: 2.94 ms
1050.432
```

CuPy is compatible with multiple CUDA versions. Installing CUDA is bit different topic, I believe CuPy documentation is doing good job guiding to the right places.
https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html

Check first, if you really need GPU. Pure Numpy, when used properly, gives really decent speeds.

Comment: any timeline with cupy? I have an amd gpu so getting it to work will be complicated

Comment: Done. I also updated my answer, since apply_along_axis was unnecesary. Execution times are now reasonable. 6ms with pure Numpy and 2.9 ms with Cupy. I believe the bigger the arrays, the more GPU may speed up.

Comment: This is great, doing np.mean(np.dot(a, b.T)) and making sure they're all np.arrays is the fastest so far